# Tensorflow GPU error: Resource Exhausted in middle of training a model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a model (implementation of a research paper) on K80 GPU with 12GB memory available for training. The dataset is about 23 GB and after data extraction, it shrinks to 12GB for the training script.

At about 4640th step (max_steps being 500,000), I receive the following error saying Resource Exhausted and the script stops soon after that.  - [image: Resource Exhausted Error]

The memory usage at the beginning of the script is:
[image]

I went through a lot of similar questions and found that reducing the batch-size might help but I have reduced the batch-size to 50 and the error persists. Is there any other solution except switching to a more powerful GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look like a GPU Out Of Memory (OOM) error but more like you ran out of space on your local drive to save the checkpoint of your model.

Are you sure that you have enough space on your disk or that the folder you save to doesn't have a quotta?

Comment: I too think it is not a GPU OOM. If you think its a OOM then,
1. Restart the process periodically. Checkpoint every step 10000 steps and stop the training process and restart. This will reset the memory fragmentation.
2.Set TF_CUDNN_WORKSPACE_LIMIT_IN_MB to a smaller number. The default is 4GB.

Comment: Correct, just checked and the disk was running out of space. Was able to fix it before I checked the answer though. Thanks a lot however :)